# HVAC System on 100 Amp Panel

Tags: electrical, hvac

I just moved into a house which has large in-wall AC units and heaters. I've been looking into replacing that setup with an HVAC system, but I only have a 100 amp panel. Given that there is already a washer and dryer, a dish washer, and other standard appliances, is this going to be an issue?

Comment: Can we have the nameplates on the existing and proposed replacement HVAC systems, the square footage of your house, the number of kitchen countertop receptacle circuits installed, and the nameplate ratings of any other large/permanently-installed appliances?

Comment: Also where do you live in my area a 40 amps of 240 cooling will handle 5 tons that will cool a 3000 sf home well but heating runs closer to 80A in an all electric home in the Pacific north west.

Comment: Are the existing heaters electric?

Comment: Getting a central forced air HVAC system will be very expensive and it will probably use more electric  power than the current distributed system. /window a/c units and through the wall a/c units have a very high SEER and they can be conveniently turned on and shut off in individual rooms. This saves a lot of power. (One way these units increase SEER is to use the condensed water to help cool the condenser coil. In a central a/c unit the chilled condensate is just dumped. I'm not sure if mini-split systems use this water to cool the condenser.)

Answer (score 2):

As always, the answer is 'it depends' and 'do a proper load calc'.

It will depend on how large a unit you're installing, but I wouldn't expect to have issues, especially as you'd be removing existing aircon and (presumably electric) heating. The new unit would likely be significantly more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

For a retrofit to a house without ducting for central HVAC, you should definitely consider so called mini-split ductless heat pump units. Some of these are extremely efficient. It is also possible to shut off a/c to individual rooms during parts of the 24 hr cycle that the room is not being occupied. So the last person at night to leave the den turns off the a/c to that room and bedrooms are only air conditioned at night or when someone is sleeping. This gives a reduction in power consumption that is in a realm beyond what a central air handler with ducts can possibly achieve.

Comment: Some these mini-split systems have a single condensing unit feed more than one air handler. Some feed one or two air handlers and operate on 120 V power. https://www.acwholesalers.com/LG-Air-Conditioners/LMU30CHV-LMN078HVT-LMN078HVT-Ductless-Dual-Zone-Heat-Pump/57041.ac?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIy6bur_W21QIVlI5-Ch2bbwo0EAEYASAFEgLhP_D_BwE